# My Stacked LSTM seems to be doing worse than a shallower one

Tags: neural-network, lstm, overfitting

I started with a two layer LSTM (+ Dense Layers) and which was:

```
my_model.add(LSTM(units = 64,input_shape = (33,1), return_sequences=(True)))
my_model.add(LSTM(units = 128))
```

This gave me not great, but not terrible losses as shown

[image]

My guess was that while my model is still learning,it would work a lot better with more layers, but it only got worse with an extra layer.

I implemented the stacking like this:

```
my_model.add(LSTM(units = 64,input_shape = (33,1), return_sequences=(True)))
my_model.add(LSTM(units = 128, return_sequences=(True)))
my_model.add(LSTM(units = 128))
```

And the result I got is significantly worse:
[image]

This really makes no sense to me. My guess is that it could be a case of and undertrained model caused by not enough data.

Edit: The rest of my model (common for both cases)

```
my_model.add(Dense(100))
my_model.add(Dense(10))
my_model.add(Dense(1))
opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.003)#changed from 0.001
my_model.compile(loss = 'mse',optimizer = opt, metrics = ['mean_squared_error'])
my_model.fit(X_train,y_train, batch_size = 512,epochs = 100,validation_data=(X_val,y_val),shuffle=True)
```

Comment: Are you using keras?

Comment: Yes I am. all my layers are imported through Keras

Comment: Can you post the full model?

Comment: Of course. I will just make an edit to the code.

Comment: Did you try just a single fc layer, i.e. Dense(1) right after LSTM? Your model is quite small, it should work fine.

Comment: I shall try it out. Would too many dense layers be a problem? I am not sure why that might happen.

Comment: your learning rate is quite high, set it to 1e-4 or 1e-5. How much data do you have?

Comment: There is a total of 214200 time-serieses and each has a sequence of 33 values. So (214200,33,1)

Comment: OK try with a lower lr and a single fc layer, see what you get

Comment: Tried that out. Now both my losses are decreasing  a bit, but there is a massive gap between the two

Comment: Keep the lr low, also set weight decay hyperparameter to 1e-3, and add back the fc layers

Comment: Decreased learning rate. It is much neater. But the test losses are still almost stagnant and there is still a lot of spikes too.

I will try out weight decay now and see what I get. 

Thanks.

Comment: Test or val loss?

Comment: My validation losses.

Comment: IF val is higher than train, but keeps decreasing it's fine

Comment: Its the opposite. Near zero and stangnant. That weirds me out

Comment: that could be a datasets problem. Could you permute/split it again into train/val

Comment: Split it again? https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/87915/my-validation-set-losses-are-static This post has my code