# My validation set losses are static

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, regression, dataset

My dataset looks something like this:

```
    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30  31  32  33
0   0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 1.0 2.0 2.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 3.0 1.0 0.0
1   0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
2   0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 3.0 2.0 0.0 1.0 3.0 1.0
3   0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0
4   0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
```

And my dataset varies like crazy as shown in mine `dataset.describe()`

```
    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30  31  32  33
count   214200.000000   214200.000000   214200.000000   214200.000000   214200.000000   214200.000000   214200.000000   214200.000000   214200.000000   214200.000000   214200.000000   214200.000000   214200.000000   214200.000000   214200.000000   214200.000000   214200.000000   214200.000000   214200.000000   214200.000000   214200.000000   214200.000000   214200.000000   214200.000000   214200.000000   214200.000000   214200.000000   214200.000000   214200.000000   214200.000000   214200.000000   214200.000000   214200.000000   214200.000000
mean    0.096228    0.103469    0.147521    0.096657    0.108880    0.151751    0.139869    0.150999    0.205892    0.185588    0.207502    0.318478    0.195868    0.200019    0.229104    0.172759    0.199748    0.208492    0.206004    0.247241    0.225037    0.248922    0.323800    0.485752    0.315481    0.254888    0.256083    0.275196    0.263193    0.241839    0.244188    0.278137    0.274622    0.293413
std 1.031383    1.130085    1.815386    0.952851    2.026803    3.965382    3.190181    3.295184    4.714035    3.830216    4.102940    5.567510    3.112597    3.127541    3.482804    2.464995    2.763012    3.120215    2.655728    2.833560    2.998698    3.040342    4.229684    5.561023    4.079211    1.879339    1.723709    4.119686    3.828952    2.286223    2.143116    2.149646    2.498978    5.550976
min -2.000000   -1.000000   -1.000000   -1.000000   -1.000000   -1.000000   -1.000000   -2.000000   -1.000000   -1.000000   -4.000000   -1.000000   -1.000000   -1.000000   -1.000000   -1.000000   -1.000000   -1.000000   -1.000000   -1.000000   -1.000000   -1.000000   -1.000000   -1.000000   -1.000000   -1.000000   -2.000000   -1.000000   -1.000000   -1.000000   -1.000000   -1.000000   -1.000000   -1.000000
25% 0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000
50% 0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000
75% 0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000
max 169.000000  117.000000  259.000000  151.000000  504.000000  766.000000  799.000000  820.000000  950.000000  978.000000  989.000000  1305.000000 899.000000  941.000000  776.000000  597.000000  602.000000  771.000000  563.000000  591.000000  639.000000  634.000000  772.000000  1209.000000 1000.000000 257.000000  174.000000  813.000000  742.000000  444.000000  482.000000  436.000000  473.000000  2253.000000
```

And we can see how far apart the max values are from the means.

My model is:

```
X_train, X_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(X_train, y_train, test_size=0.15)
my_model = Sequential()
my_model.add(LSTM(units = 64,input_shape = (33,1),return_sequences=True,kernel_regularizer=l2(0.00001),bias_regularizer=l2(0.00001), recurrent_regularizer=l2(0.00001)))
my_model.add(LSTM(units = 128, return_sequences=True,kernel_regularizer=l2(0.00001),bias_regularizer=l2(0.00001), recurrent_regularizer=l2(0.00001)))
my_model.add(Dense(100, kernel_regularizer=l2(0.00001),bias_regularizer=l2(0.00001)))
my_model.add(Dense(10, kernel_regularizer=l2(0.00001),bias_regularizer=l2(0.00001)))
my_model.add(Dense(1))
opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.0002)#changed from 0.001
my_model.compile(loss = 'mse',optimizer = opt, metrics = ['mean_squared_error'])
my_model.summary()
history=my_model.fit(X_train,y_train, batch_size = 512,epochs = 100,validation_data=(X_val,y_val),shuffle=True)  ## Removing the shuffle cause shuffle seems to undo the CV
```

But despite whatever tweaking I do, my validation losses just choose a low constant value and stick to it like gospel. I have tried changing learning rates, models and everything. My loss is always something along those lines.

[image]

Comment: Aren't the labels in the graph swapped? the training loss is supposed to be lower than the test set loss, right?

Comment: Labels aren't wrong. That is the problem with my model. For some reason losses are essentially locked into a value.

No one else that submitted to Kaggle has used validation sets and that could be part of it

Comment: I'm probably not the right person to help with this, but this is quite confusing to me: first could you explain what the task is about? You're trying to model the whole sequence, right? I could imagine that if the variations in the sequence are made of noise, the model just doesn't capture any pattern and sticks to some basic pattern.

Comment: That is my basic guess too. There is a series that I am trying to predict. My task is basically to model and predict the last value of a series. Except, there is a bunch of outliers and the standard deviation of my last column is around 5 with a mean of 0. 

The way I see it, maybe my model just predicts a value around that range and returns it back to me.